# GE convection/microwave just quit. No heat. micro does not heat either. All else works. Lights, fan, timer, etc

Tags: appliances

GE Conv/Micro  just stopped heating either way. All else works.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. All we could say would be "sounds like it needs servicing." And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Is this the only thing that stopped working?

Comment: do you have a specific question?

Comment: Also, microwaves are one thing that are not user-repairable in the vast majority of circumstances.

Comment: Microvave ovens have a small electronic micro controller inside, when it dies, the important parts of the system will not function. As a general rule, replacing that "motherboard" will cost you as much as a new oven, and then you have a new board on old parts.

Answer (score -1):

#### One hot dead

A typical **big** oven (as opposed to a countertop/portable oven) in the US uses 240V for heating (possibly including microwave) and 120V for controls/lights/fans. The power is connected (ideally, not always due to "old stuff", among other things) with 2 hot wires, 1 neutral wire and 1 ground wire. The 120V items use one hot + neutral. The 240V items use two hots. If the hot used for 120V is good but the *other* hot is out, then controls/lights/fans will work but you won't get any heat.

Check your circuit breaker. A 240V/120V oven should be on a pair of breakers. They definitely should have common shutoff (i.e., if you manually flip the breaker off, **both** hots are disconnected at the same time) but they might not have **common trip**. So turn the pair of breakers off/on and see if that helps. **IF YOU DON'T have a PAIR of breakers side-by-side, STOP** and don't do anything else without posting some pictures to diagnose some more.

If resetting the breakers doesn't solve the problem then you likely have a loose connection somewhere:

- Wires coming out of oven
- Wires going into plug (if it is plug/receptacle rather than hard-wired)
- Wires going into receptacle (if it is plug/receptacle rather than hard-wired)
- Connection between wires coming from oven and wires from breakers in a junction box in the wall (if hard-wired)
- Wires going into breakers

Before working on **ANY** of those wires, turn the breakers off.

Comment: It is fairly unlikely that a microwave would be fed 240V.

Comment: Haven't found a GE yet, but in a quick search found a KitchenAid 240V convection/microwave oven https://www.homedepot.com/p/KitchenAid-1-4-cu-ft-Built-In-Convection-Microwave-in-Stainless-Steel-KMBP107ESS/205982322